# Compatibility of dynamic lib(.so) version

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linux-kernel, shared-libraries

I have a software compiled and running on centos 5, Now i am intrested in running it on Centos 6, unmodified without compilation on new machine.

Here is the challenge:-
My process requires certain lib say *libcap.so.1* but centos 6 has newer version say *libcap.so.2*

I am able to make old software work with any of below hacks

1. create a symlink(libcap.so.1) to libcap.so.2
2. copy libcap.so.1 to new machine(centos 6)

What is recommended between two and are there any known issues with this approach, compiling on centos6 would be my last option.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a sym link like that will sometimes work, depending on what exactly the changes were that led to the new version - they would have to be minimal changes that especially did not remove access to any routines/variables that the old library had or drastically change the signature of any of the routines/variables that remain. If the library uses symbol versioning (like the `gcc` standard C library does), it's possible the `.2` version still contains the full API the previous version provided, but I don't know off the top of my head if `libpcap` does that...

If the new library does not encapsulate the old API, your safest bet is to recompile. If your application is not mission-critical, and/or you can deal with crashes and the possibility of corrupted data, it shouldn't hurt (much) to just try the sym link route...

Comment: thx, are there any known issues if old lib is copied and coexists with new one?

Comment: There shouldn't be... You can have the `.1` and the `.2` both installed. Usually, the `.so` (without the version number) will point to the latest, so that newly compiled stuff will use the newer version. You might need to install the files manually, though, as the library may have been packaged to only allow one version installed at a time.

Comment: This mechanism was created especially to allow multiple versions of the same library to coexist. Distributions should not prohibit parallel installation unless there is a very good reason to do so.

Comment: @SimonRichter Agreed... But that doesn't mean they don't, at least in practice. Generally when a new update is installed, the old version is removed. Whether that's because only one version is allowed, or that's just the "standard procedure" for the package manager depends on the distro...